# android recyclerview json load more items

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

I'm having this problem a little while, I need to load 25+ items from a database in json. When I load all of the including images etc. the app takes ages to load all of them. So I thought could I load the first five and when I scroll to the bottom the second five and so on. But it does not work. Here is my code:

Scroll listener:

```
rec.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            visible = lin.getChildCount();
            total = lin.getItemCount();
            past = lin.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if ((visible + past) >= total){
                new HttpAsyncTask().loadMore();
            }
        }
    });
```

AsyncTask:

```
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<PostsData>> {
    int next;
    @Override
    protected List<PostsData> doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            //get json from url
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject("{'posts':"+GET("http://www.website.com/json")+"}");
            //get json array
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("posts");
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    next = i;
                    PostsData data = new PostsData();
                    //get object from array
                    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    //title
                    data.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    //id
                    data.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                    JSONObject cat = jsonObject.getJSONObject("category");
                    //category name
                    data.setCatagorie(cat.getString("name"));
                    JSONObject img = jsonObject.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
                    //image url
                    String imgUrl = img.getString("preview_url");
                    //convert url into bitmap
                    data.setImage(getBitmap(imgUrl));

                    //get the post submitter name from array 'makers'
                    String makerFullname = "";
                    JSONArray userArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("makers");
                    for (int j = 0; j < userArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject user = userArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        //submitter full name
                        makerFullname = user.getString("full_name");
                        data.setUser(makerFullname);
                    }

                    data.setSubmitUser(jsonObject.getJSONObject("submitter").getString("full_name"));

                    //get the like count of the post
                    data.setLikeCount(jsonObject.getString("upvotes_count"));

                    list.add(data);
                }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

    // onPostExecute displays th
    // results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<PostsData> result) {
        adapter = new PostsAdapter(result, getContext());
        rec.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void loadMore(){
        try {
            //get json from url
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject("{'posts':" + GET("http://www.materialup.com/api/v1/posts") + "}");
            //get json array
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("posts");
            if (array.length() <= next) {
                for (int i = 0; i < next + 5; i++) {
                    next = i;
                    PostsData data = new PostsData();
                    //get object from array
                    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    //title
                    data.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    //id
                    data.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                    JSONObject cat = jsonObject.getJSONObject("category");
                    //category name
                    data.setCatagorie(cat.getString("name"));
                    JSONObject img = jsonObject.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
                    //image url
                    String imgUrl = img.getString("preview_url");
                    //convert url into bitmap
                    data.setImage(getBitmap(imgUrl));

                    //get the post submitter name from array 'makers'
                    String makerFullname = "";
                    JSONArray userArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("makers");
                    for (int j = 0; j < userArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject user = userArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        //submitter full name
                        makerFullname = user.getString("full_name");
                        data.setUser(makerFullname);
                    }

                    data.setSubmitUser(jsonObject.getJSONObject("submitter").getString("full_name"));

                    //get the like count of the post
                    data.setLikeCount(jsonObject.getString("upvotes_count"));

                    list.add(data);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }.....
```

It just won't load the next 5 items in the recyclerview. I searched on google but I did not really understand how load more works.

Thanks in advance, Sven.

This is the tutorial I followed: [here](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-ListView-load-more-items.htm)

Comment: this `JSONObject object = new JSONObject("{'posts':"+GET("http://www.website.com/json")+"}");
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("posts");` is disturbing... why don't you just `JSONArray array = new JSONArray(GET("http://www.website.com/json"));`?

Comment: anyway. It looks like you are always loading the same 5 items.

Comment: It works to retrieve the posts, but thanks for reminding.

Comment: Yes exactly that is my problem

Comment: I really don't know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Make the next variable a static variable and start the loadMore method for statement with `i=next+1,i <next+6` to avoid loading the same data again